# symfony doctrine auto increment migrations insert column count mismatch

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to add inserts to a migration but it is complaining about column mismatch because I am not including the auto increment id field, it works if I ad the id column but it should be auto increment and I should not need to add it ?? any help greatly appreciated.

entity file

```
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

migration file

```
 /**
 * @param Schema $schema
 */
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql("INSERT INTO shipping_rates VALUES
    (0,'Ground','2',5.64 )

    ");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not also provide the columns in the insert statement?

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi